# Pointer problem in C for char*

Tags: c, char, printing

i  use pointer for  holding name and  research lab  property. But when i print the  existing  Vertex   ,when i print the vertex, i cant see so -called attributes properly.
For example though real value of name is ***"lancelot"*** , i see it as wrong  such as ***"asdasdasdasd"***

```
struct vertex {
                int value;
                char*name;
                char* researchLab;
                struct vertex *next;
                struct edge *list;
};
    void GRAPHinsertV(Graph G, int value,char*name,char*researchLab) {
    //create new  Vertex.
        Vertex newV = malloc(sizeof newV);
        // set  value of new variable  to which belongs the person.
        newV->value = value;
        newV->name=name;
        newV->researchLab=researchLab;
        newV->next = G->head;
        newV->list = NULL;
        G->head = newV;
        G->V++;
    }

    /***
    The method   creates new person.
    **/
    void createNewPerson(Graph G) {
        int id;
        char name[30];
        char researchLab[30];
        // get requeired variables.
        printf("Enter id of the person to be added.\n");
        scanf("%d",&id);
        printf("Enter name of the person to be added.\n");
        scanf("%s",name);
        printf("Enter researc lab of the person to  be added\n");
        scanf("%s",researchLab);
        // insert the people to the social network.
        GRAPHinsertV(G,id,name,researchLab);
    }
    void ListAllPeople(Graph G)
    {
        Vertex tmp;
        Edge list;
        for(tmp = G->head;tmp!=NULL;tmp=tmp->next)
        {
            fprintf(stdout,"V:%d\t%s\t%s\n",tmp->value,tmp->name,tmp->researchLab);

        }
        system("pause");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this:

```
   newV->name=name;
   newV->researchLab=researchLab;
```

You are copying the *pointer* to the strings `name` and `researchLab`. You are not copying the *strings* themselves. In other words, after this, `newV->name` and `name` point to exactly the same location in memory where the name is stored; you have not created a duplicate copy of the data.

Since you then proceed to overwrite the `name` array in the `createNewPerson` function, at the end of this function, all of your `vertex` structs will have their `name` attribute pointing to the same memory location, which is only storing the last name entered.

Worse, when `createNewPerson` returns, its local `name` array goes out of scope, and is re-used for other things. Since your vertex structs are still pointing here for their `name` attributes, this is how you get garbage.

You need to duplicate the string. A simple way to do it is:

```
newV->name = strdup(name);
```

You will need to `#include <string.h>` to get the `strdup` library function.

And then you also need to make sure that you call `free` on the `name` attribute whenever you are disposing of a `vertex` structure.

Answer (score 4):

`GRAPHinsertV` copies the *pointer* of the `name` and `researchLab` strings to the vector structure.

`createNewPerson` creates a *temporary* for the `name` and `researchLab` strings.

The problem here is, you're pointing to a *temporary* string which causes **undefined behaviour** when you access it after `createNewPerson` returns.

To solve this problem, you can duplicate the strings in `GRAPHinsertV` using `malloc`+`strcpy`, or by using the non-standard `strdup`.

Comment: `strdup` may not be ISO C, but it is POSIX, so it's only "non-standard" in the sense that `select` et. al. are "non-standard".

Comment: @Tyler, Yeah, I doing my homework on `strdup` and realized it wasn't a GNU extension as I thought, but part of the POSIX standard.  I think that note is best left in the comments, though.

Answer (score 0):

The name variable you pass to GRAPHinsertV() is allocated on the stack for createNewPerson(), so the pointer points to a local variable. Once the activations records are popped off that value can (and will) be overwritten by subsequent code.

You need to allocate memory on the heap if you are only going to keep a char * in the struct.

Ex. Instead of

```
char name[30];
```

you could use

```
char *name = (char *)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
```

but keep in mind if you manually allocate it you have to take care of freeing it as well, otherwise it will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the char *name pointer, like

```
newV->name=name;
```

You're not creating a new string, but making the newV.name member point to the same memory as the char[] array that was passed in. You'll need to malloc() or otherwise allocate a new char[] array in order to obtain separate storage for each structure.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem here:

```
Vertex newV = malloc(sizeof newV);
```

It should be

```
Vertex *newV = malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
```

Comment: I'm guessing `Vertex` is a typedef of `vertex*`, given the difference in capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating memory in the function `createNewPerson()` that lasts exactly as long as `createNewPerson()` is executing, and is available for overwriting immediately after it returns.  You need to copy the text fields in with something like `strdup(newV->name, name)`, rather than point to the local variables in `createNewPerson()`.  (If your implementation doesn't have `strdup()`, you can easily define it as:

```
char * strdup(const char *inp)
{
    char * s = malloc(strlen(inp) + 1);
    strcpy(s, inp);
    return s;
}
```

In addition, your I/O has potential problems.  If you enter my name, "David Thornley", for the name, it'll take "David" as the name and "Thornley" as the lab, since "%s" searches for a whitespace-delimited string.  If I enter "Forty-two" for the ID, nothing will be put in `id`, and "Forty-two" will be used for the name.  If I enter a name or lab name over 29 characters, it will overwrite other memory.

I'd suggest using `fgets()` to get one line of input per answer, then use `sscanf()` to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

When passing and assigning strings, always make a copy of them. There're no guarantees that the string you received is still in the memory afterwards, since the pointer could have been freed.

Of course, if you are only going to use `name` inside the function (that's, you're not going to assign it to a variable *outside* the scope of the function), you don't have to do the copy.

In order to do that, inside `GRAPHinsertV`, instead of

```
newV->name=name;
```

do

```
if (name != NULL)     // Preventing using null pointer
{
    newV->name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    strcpy(newV->name, name);
}
```